# refactor cferror tag to application.cfc's onError()

Tags: coldfusion, application.cfc

How to translate

```
<cferror type="EXCEPTION" template="ErrorTemplate.cfm">
```

to an `onError()` function for Application.cfc?  Notice that cferror create a var `error` struct for the template.  Is there a quick and easy way to create the same error struct?  How to pass that into ErrorTemplate.cfm using `<cfinclude>`?

I know `onRequest()` shares the variable scope with the target page, but does onError share variables scope too?  If not, what shall I do? Stick it to the `Form` scope?

Thank you

Comment: came across http://ketanjetty.com/coldfusion/basics/error-handling/ and it says "If you are using Application.cfc the best palce to use CFERROR tags is in the onRequestStart() method." really?

Comment: Weird. Does that actually work? (I cannot test it now). I always thought it had to be placed *outside* the functions in Application.cfc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/appFramework_15.html

> Consider replacing cferror tags with an onError event method. If you
>   do not do so, put the cferror tags in the CFC initialization code.

According to http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2007/12/5/The-Complete-Guide-to-Adding-Error-Handling-to-Your-ColdFusion-Application

> What if you are using Application.cfc? Well one thing to remember is
>   that you can just as easily put CFERROR tags inside your
>   Application.cfc file. That is allowed, and I've done that before.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you not just use onError in App.cfc to display a "Sorry and error occurred, we are working on it" type page?

Comment: The existing error template relies on the error struct provided by cferror

Comment: Dump and mail the error to yourself within onError.  I also email url, cgi, session and application variable onError to ensure I fix problems when they arise.