# ColdFusion Issue using OnError

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10

I am trying to replace my **cferror** tag(which was in application.cfm) with **onError** method (in application.cfc which will replace application.cfm).
But I am facing an issue.
The issue is :

> For **onError**, If i tried to display some user friendly message, it is
>   being displayed in the html at the place where the error is occured.
>   For example, If exception is occured in the footer, then the message
>   is displayed in the footer of the site and everything else(html) on
>   the site is also displayed.
>   But when i was using **cferror** tag, If
>   exception is occured, then only that template is being displayed which
>   is specified in cferror tag.

So,
Is there any way to make the **onError** to work same as **cferror** tag?
(In sense of displaying user-friendly message)

Thanks.

Comment: So what exactly you need, need to show Generic way of Showing a Message and even the Issue comes up anywhere, you can try the following

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're describing makes sense. The output buffer is already part-filled with a response for the client.

In your onError method in application.cfc, you ought to be able to use `<cfcontent reset=true>` to empty the buffer, then you can send whatever response you like.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your Application.cfc

```
<cffunction name="onError" returnType="void" output="true">
    <cfargument name="exception" required="true">
    <cfargument name="eventname" type="string" required="true">
    <cfset var errortext = "">
    <cflog file="myapperrorlog" text="#arguments.exception.message#">
    <cfsavecontent variable="errortext">
    <cfoutput>
    An error occurred: http://#cgi.server_name##cgi.script_name#?#cgi.query_string#<br />
    Time: #dateFormat(now(), "short")# #timeFormat(now(), "short")#<br />
    <cfdump var="#arguments.exception#" label="Error">
    <cfdump var="#form#" label="Form">
    <cfdump var="#url#" label="URL">
    </cfoutput>
    </cfsavecontent>
    <cfmail to="emails@yourdomain.com" subject="Error: #arguments.exception.message#" attributeCollection="#request.mailDetails#">
        #errortext#
    </cfmail>
    <cflocation url="errors.cfm">
</cffunction>
```

Create a generic errors.cfm Page and where you can show some custom Message to the User, You can add whatever message you want to diplay to the user and in the mail, you can add your own email, so everytime the error comes up, you will get an email.

Comment: can not use cflocation, as it will change the url. Want it to be same as is for cferror tag.

Comment: Hi, if you use cferror, you need to use the template as per Adobe documentation: `<cferror 
    template = "template path"
    type = "exception|validation|request"
    exception = "exception type"
    mailTo = "e-mail address">`. So in the onError Method, you can or cannot specify the template, its choice of yours, so apparently if no template is specified, it will show error where it encounters as that is the default way how it works

Comment: I am using cfinclude to specify template in onError. So it is shown where the error is encountered. But i want it to work like CfError tag. So it will remove everything on the page and only that specific template is displayed. Is it possible using cfError?

Comment: You mean to say you need to use error.diagnotics, error scope fields which are available in cferror

Comment: Check this Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101485/refactor-cferror-tag-to-application-cfcs-onerror